Generate new Column in Dataframe with Modulo of other Column
I would like to create a new column "Day2" which takes the second digit of column named "Days", so if we have Days equal to 35, we would take the number 5 to be in "Day2", I tried this but it's not working:
DF["Day2"] = DF["Days"].where(
            DF["Days"] < 10,
            (DF["Days"] / 10 % 10).astype(int),
        )

It seems it's taking the first digit but never the second one, can someone help?

This is a very simple and pythonic solution:
import pandas as pd

data = [10,11,35,45,65]

df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns=['Day1'])

df['Day2'] = df['Day1'].mod(10)

df

Result
       Day1 Day2
   0    10  0
   1    11  1
   2    35  5
   3    45  5
   4    65  5

